# Getting files to/from android phone

Tags: usb, android, media, mtp, ptp

I am having trouble to access the filesystem on my phone (it's a samsung / google galaxy nexus).  It just worked in previous version of Ubuntu, but now it appears empty whether it is mounted with MTP or PTP.  I have followed a few guides on building and reinstalling libmtp etc without success.  [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87667/getting-mtp-to-work-with-a-galaxy-nexus) did not help for me, either, and gMTP just hangs when I click the connect button.  I know I can use wifi e.g. airdroid to access my photos, but this is too slow and a bit clumsy for me, and downloaded photos lose their original timestamps.

Has anyone had success connecting to this phone on 12.04 ??

Comment: Do any of the [answers here](http://askubuntu.com/q/143350/12864) help?

Comment: nope ` ` ` ` ` `

Comment: Did you try banshee, i have Samsung Galaxy s2, and with banshee it works fine. pictures/music/videos. try that out :)

Comment: just tried, my device doesn't show up in banshee

Comment: I had exaclty the same problem, pls if you found some solution publish it here. Thanks.

Comment: no solution yet, i'm still limping along with wifi/airdroid.  i will start a bounty.

Comment: Are you using a custom rom by any chance?

Comment: no, my phone is stock as a rock

Comment: Cant you use mass storage mode? In Galaxy S2 i find the option under Settings->Wireless & network - More.... -> Usb utilities.

Comment: yes, i've heard about that for galaxy s2, but usb utilities is not there for galaxy nexus.

Comment: Did you disable ADB (usb debugging) in dev- options?

Comment: i've attempted with that enabled and disabled

Comment: Check [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1773598) out, as well.. Interesting script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I wrote in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/a/187710/63606), there are several solutions.

Given that you don't have a rooted phone, you can't install [Samba Filesharing](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.funkyfresh.samba) and have traditional `samba` shares on your phone.

But looking at [this thread](http://androidforums.com/international-gsm-galaxy-nexus-all-things-root/468531-samba-filesharing.html), it seems that [ASTRO File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.metago.astro) plus its [SMB Module](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.metago.astro.smb) can work even without `root access` (not tested by me, can't confirm). [AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid) could be another alternative to test.

Answer (score 11):

### Pre-requisites

First, install the necessary packages:

```
sudo apt-get install mtp-tools mtpfs
```

### A bit of elbow grease

Connect your Android phone to your computer. On your phone, open up the notification drawer, and click on `USB Connection type`. Make sure that `MTP` is selected.

[image: MTP Mode]

Now, run these commands on Ubuntu:

```
mtp-detect | grep idVendor
mtp-detect | grep idProduct
```

Note down the numbers written in front of `idVendor` and `idProduct`. You'll need those later on.

---

Now, run this command:

gksu gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules

A `Gedit` window should open up. Type this text in it, all in a single line:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="VENDORID", ATTR{idProduct}=="PRODUCTID", MODE="0666"
```

Replace VENDORID with the idVendor you had noted down earlier. Similarly, replace PRODUCTID with the idProduct you had noted down.

Save and close the file.

---

Disconnect your phone and run these commands:

```
sudo service udev restart
sudo mkdir /media/androiddevice
sudo chmod a+rwx /media/androiddevice
sudo adduser yourusername fuse
```

Replace `yourusername` with your Ubuntu user name. Now, run this command:

```
gksu gedit /etc/fuse.conf
```

In the `Gedit` window, remove the `#` at the beginning of the last line (the one that begins with `#user_allow_other`). Close and save the file.

---

Restart your computer, and then run these three commands:

```
echo "alias android-connect=\"mtpfs -o allow_other /media/androiddevice\"" >> ~/.bashrc
echo "alias android-disconnect=\"fusermount -u /media/androiddevice\"" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

---

Reconnect your phone, make sure it's still in `MTP` mode, and then run this command:

```
android-connect
```

### Ta-dam!

You may now browse your Android phone's contents using Nautilus. Just fire up the file manager, and then in the side bar click on your phone's name to browse your phone's filesystem just like you would with a USB stick. You can add, remove and modify files just like a normal file system.

[image: Phone filesystem]

---

You might have noticed, however, that you cannot use the Nautilus eject icon to disconnect the phone. Instead, to safely remove the phone, you need to run the command:

```
android-disconnect
```

From now on, you will need to run `android-connect` to mount your phone and then `android-disconnect` to safely remove your phone. Everything else should be handled automatically.

> **Note:** These two commands won't require root permissions to run. All users who are members of the `fuse` user group should be able to run these commands without root access.

### You're done

That's it! You've successfully connected your Ice Cream Sandwich phone to your Ubuntu computer.

---

<sub>*Source: [OMG! Ubuntu!](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/12/how-to-connect-your-android-ice-cream-sandwich-phone-to-ubuntu-for-file-access)*</sub>

Comment: I have already tried the OMGubuntu guide and it did not work properly for me

Comment: What didn't work? Give details.

Comment: Can anyone suggest a fix for the 'connect'/'disconnect' issue?

Comment: trying to browse on the mounted share just hangs .. and the only way to unfreeze it i've found is to unplug the cable

Comment: To have this work, mtp-detect must return some device, am i wrong? @SirCharlo

Comment: @merveotesi, use `sudo` or run as root for `mtp-detect`. Regular user listed nothing for me.

Comment: this is madness

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative way to transfer data between them, you could try to use Ubuntu One on both your PC and your mobile device (tablet or phone).