# How to access an Androidphone's filesystem

Tags: filesystem, android, root

I want to have access to my rooted Android-phone's filesystem using a USB-cabel-connection and either a Terminal or File Manager with GUI. I also want to be able to edit the system files using VIM or any other text editor of my choice.

> Is this possible? How is this enabled?

I have tried [this method](https://askubuntu.com/questions/183482/getting-files-to-from-android-phone) but i got this error in the almost last step:

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
bash: alias: -o: not found
bash: alias: allow_other: not found
bash: alias: /media/androiddevice/: not found
bash: alias: -u: not found
bash: alias: /media/androiddevice/: not found
```

and `android-connect` doesnt work fine:

```
~$ android-connect 
Unable to open ~/.mtpz-data for reading, MTPZ disabled.Listing raw device(s)
Device 0 (VID=12d1 and PID=1051) is a Huawei Honor U8860.
   Found 1 device(s):
   Huawei: Honor U8860 (12d1:1051) @ bus 1, dev 7
Attempting to connect device
ignoring libusb_claim_interface() = -6PTP_ERROR_IO: failed to open session, trying again after resetting USB interface
LIBMTP libusb: Attempt to reset device
inep: usb_get_endpoint_status(): Resource temporarily unavailable
outep: usb_get_endpoint_status(): Device or resource busy
ignoring libusb_claim_interface() = -6LIBMTP PANIC: failed to open session on second attempt
Unable to open raw device 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to connect to your android phone through **adb**

Then you can type in your terminal "**adb shell**" and then "**su**" to have root access to your phone's files through your Ubuntu terminal.