# Browse Android's external SD card from Ubuntu PC

Tags: usb, nautilus, android, sd-card

I followed [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/183482/getting-files-to-from-android-phone/196417#196417) to get access to my Android phone from my Ubuntu PC and everything went well except I don't have access to my Android's SD card.

*The [guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/183482/getting-files-to-from-android-phone/196417#196417) uses the "mtp-tools mtpfs" to browse android phone's contents using Nautilus, by the nautilus side bar, like it would with a USB stick.*

How can I now browse my Android phone's SD external card's contents?

Comment: 12.04 is past end of life.  You should upgrade to a supported release.

Comment: Organic Marble My graphics card cannot support 14.04 or better. I think I'm not the only one.

Comment: @AntonyMan if you're talking AMD GPU, 18.04 supports that again... (not all of them: check)

Comment: I tried 18.3 MATE with no luck! :(  Not even can upgrade to 14 is supported by my pc because of graphics card!

Answer (score 2):

Finally I make it with "gMTP".

*(The program gMTP it’s intended for managing MP3 players, but it works great for managing devices.)*

To install it:

```
sudo apt-get install gmtp
```

To connect:

just plug the android via the USB cable into your computer, start gMTP and click “Connect”.

*When you press "Connect" you will asked if you want to browse internal memory or sd card.*

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution :-) But as commented by @Organic Marble, the best solution for most people is to use a new version of Ubuntu, which has built-in support for android devices.

Comment: The best I can get is 12.04 and I think I'm not the only one. (So, I'm "fighting" to use my [only] [old] pc which can run windows7 but no any newer version than ubuntu 12.) :(

Comment: I see. Have you tried with some light-weight flavour of Ubuntu (Lubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Ubuntu Budgie or Xubuntu)? Standard Ubuntu may want more modern hardware for graphics, but these flavours have lighter desktop environments, that might work. If there are problems with the linux driver for graphics, the problem is worse.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have tried Linux Mint 18.3 MATE with no luck.

Comment: What is your cormputer and graphics card/chip (brand name and model for both of them)? How much RAM is there?

Comment: CPU: Intel P4A 2.4GHz (4.5x533)
    Motherboard: Gigabyte GA-8PE667 pro
    Chipset: Intel Brookdale i845PE
    Memory: 1536 MB (DDR-SDRAM)
    BIOS: Award Modular (10/16/'02)
    Graphics: nVidia GeForce 4 Ti or FX 5200 (128MB both)
    HD: IDE ATA

Comment: I have a Dell with a Dell Dimension 4600 with a P4 CPU and old nvidia graphics. It works with the current versions of Lubuntu including 18.04 LTS (32-bit). I have also 1536 MB (DDR-SDRAM) and a NV34 [GeForce FX 5200]. The linux free graphics driver 'nouveau' works. It runs idle using 148 MB RAM (but needs at least 1 GB to be able to do real work browsing the internet). Lubuntu 16.04 LTS works too in my Dell, so I think you can upgrade to a current version. I am testing right now booted from a USB pendrive cloned with mkusb from `lubuntu-18.04-desktop-i386.iso`.

Comment: If you must boot from a CD, you can download Xubuntu Core 18.04 LTS (32-bit), an iso file that is small enough. A member of the Xubuntu development group has uploaded iso files at [unit193.net/xubuntu/core](https://unit193.net/xubuntu/core/)